# JUnit: Run via eclipse and maven test. Big difference in the speed, why?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, maven-2, junit4

I have one JUnit class and this class contains couple test methods.
I am trying run this test class via `Eclipse IDE` menu *Run As -> Junit* Test.

Execution Speed:

1 time. **30 sec.**

2 time: **29 sec.**

3 time: **23 sec.**

After this, I am trying execute test class via `maven run` in the terminal.
In this case execution speed:

1 time: **1 min. 10 sec.**

2 time: **59 sec.**

3 time: **56 sec.**

So, as you can see, wee have really big difference between those two cases.  But how can we explain this big difference?

P.S. I am using latest version Eclipse IDE and maven.

Comment: Re-run the maven once more and do let us know the output . May be that was the first time for some jar to download, and that time is taken into account there.

Comment: @mtk, I am experimenting with this during all day, I think, that all jar was downloaded.

Comment: how sure are you the arguments are the same? is the eclipse test runner configured with more memory maybe?

Comment: @radai, I am not sure about this. Do you know way how can I check this?

Comment: i dont know how to check what eclipse is doing, but you could give the surefire jvm more memory using this maven plugin configuration for surefire: <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <configuration>          
          <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

Comment: @radai, Generally, I don't have so much memory :) But, ok, I going to try to play with this value.

Comment: also, exactly what maven invocation are you using? maybe youre running the whole build in maven and not just the tests, so those extra 30 seconds youre seeing might be compilcation + packaging

Comment: @radai, I just go to the root directory of the project via terminal and run 'maven test' command. That are all my actions.

Comment: maven, when given a lifecycle phase (like "test") will run through _ALL_ of the lifecycle phases before that phase, which in your case probably includes compiling and packaging. try calling just the surefire plugin directly: "mvn surefire:test" (see doc here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html). more info on maven lifecycle phases is here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: @radai, first of all, thank you for the links. I think they will be very useful for me in the future. Thanks. Also, I've tried mvn surefire:test. But this hadn't an impact on time. >50 sec.

Comment: thats odd ... could you run "mvn -X surefire:test" and post the output (either in the question or pastebin or something)?

Answer (score 0):

Maven has a build lifecycle, which involves the following steps:

1. validate
2. compile
3. test
4. package
5. integration-test
6. verify
7. install
8. deploy

Eclipse just compiles and runs the test.
I think this might be the reason.

Comment: I also tried run tests via "mvn surefire:test" command. The result is same.

Comment: Running mvn surefire:test executes the following phases :    
 - process-resources
 - compile 
 - process-test-resources
 - test-compile
 - test;

This is why it is slower than just running in eclipse.
You should check this url for more details:
[Maven build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: and there are no way to skip all previous phases and just execute one phase?

Comment: You cannot skip the phases which are prior to the one you need. That's Maven. HTH).

Comment: thats wrong. mvn surefire:test is a direct plugin invocation, not a lifecycl phase invocation and will do nothing except run the tests (just verified that locally).

Comment: lifecycle isn't the problem there.  I have tests that runs for 6 hours with failsafe plugin (maven) and around 3 hours from eclipse.  Here the lifecycle "overhead" is no more than a couple of seconds.